# Parsing JSON String to Object and returning REST call

Tags: java, json

I am following a tutorial on setting up a server in PHP. I am trying to recreate the same code in Java. When the original call comes through I then make a call to an external API that gets a String response. Now when I return the value it shows on the browser as a String, while I want it to return as json.

Looking up information online I tried creating a POJO of the returned String, using `JsonParser` I am having issues trying to parse the String to the POJO.

Here's the returned String that I am trying to convert to JSON;

`{version=1.0.5, nodeversion=1.0005901E7, protocolversion=10011.0, chainname=chain1, description=MultiChain chain1, protocol=multichain, port=2645.0, setupblocks=60.0, nodeaddress=chain1@1.1.1.1:2645, burnaddress=1XXXXXXWXHXXXXXXTRXXXXXXLHXXXXXXXn2aid, incomingpaused=false, miningpaused=false, walletversion=60000.0, balance=0.0, walletdbversion=2.0, reindex=false, blocks=59.0, timeoffset=0.0, connections=0.0, proxy=, difficulty=6.0E-8, testnet=false, keypoololdest=1.530817257E9, keypoolsize=2.0, paytxfee=0.0, relayfee=0.0, errors=}`

Here is the POJO;

```
public class Info {

private String version;
private String nodeVersion;
private String protocolVersion;
private String chainName;
private String description;
private String protocol;
private String port;
private String setupBlocks;
private String nodeAddress;
private String burnAddress;
private boolean incomingPaused;
private boolean miningPaused;
private String walletVersion;
private String balance;
private String walletBVersion;
private boolean reindex;
private String blocks;
private String timeOffset;
private String connections;
private String proxy;
private String difficulty;
private boolean testnet;
private String keyPoolOldest;
private String keyPoolSize;
private String payTxFee;
private String relayFee;
private String errors;
//Constructor, Getters and Setters
}
```

And here's my controller method;

```
@RequestMapping(value="/publish/{signature}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Info getInfo(@PathVariable String signature) throws MultichainException, IOException {
    String info = multiChainCommand.getChainCommand().getInfo();
    String updated = info.replaceAll("=", ":");

    mapper.configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);

    Info info1 = mapper.readValue(updated, Info.class);
    return info1;
}
```

Looking at the PHP code from the tutorial I am doing the code looks quiet easy - `return $response->withJson($blockchain_info)->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');`

Is there an equivalent way to get this done in Java, if not how can I achieve this?

**EDIT**

Here is the parsing and the exceptions I have faced.

**Request Method**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/publish/{signature}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public Info getInfo(@PathVariable String signature) throws MultichainException, IOException {
    String info = multiChainCommand.getChainCommand().getInfo();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    Info info1 = mapper.readValue(info, Info.class);
    return info1;
}
```

**Exception**

```
2018-07-07 11:41:22.384 ERROR 31307 --- [nio-8090-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('v' (code 118)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
at [Source: (String)"{version=1.0.5, nodeversion=1.0005901E7, protocolversion=10011.0, chainname=chain1, description=MultiChain chain1, protocol=multichain, port=2645.0, setupblocks=60.0, nodeaddress=chain1@172.31.4.43:2645, burnaddress=1XXXXXXWXHXXXXXXTRXXXXXXLHXXXXXXXn2aid, incomingpaused=false, miningpaused=false, walletversion=60000.0, balance=0.0, walletdbversion=2.0, reindex=false, blocks=59.0, timeoffset=0.0, connections=0.0, proxy=, difficulty=6.0E-8, testnet=false, keypoololdest=1.530817257E9, keypoolsize=2"[truncated 40 chars]; line: 1, column: 3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804) ~[jackson-core-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:669) ~[jackson-core-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:567) ~[jackson-core-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddName(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1757) ~[jackson-core-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:682) ~[jackson-core-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3004) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
at com.example.demo.controller.MultichainController.getInfo(MultichainController.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

I looked up this issue and found a configuration setting for `ObjectMapper` and retried with the new config

**Request Method #2**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/publish/{signature}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
public Info getInfo(@PathVariable String signature) throws MultichainException, IOException {
    String info = multiChainCommand.getChainCommand().getInfo();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);

    Info info1 = mapper.readValue(info, Info.class);
    return info1;
}
```

**Exception #2**

```
2018-07-07 11:49:39.145 ERROR 31569 --- [nio-8090-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('=' (code 61)): was expecting a colon to separate field name and value
at [Source: (String)"{version=1.0.5, nodeversion=1.0005901E7, protocolversion=10011.0, chainname=chain1, description=MultiChain chain1, protocol=multichain, port=2645.0, setupblocks=60.0, nodeaddress=chain1@172.31.4.43:2645, burnaddress=1XXXXXXWXHXXXXXXTRXXXXXXLHXXXXXXXn2aid, incomingpaused=false, miningpaused=false, walletversion=60000.0, balance=0.0, walletdbversion=2.0, reindex=false, blocks=59.0, timeoffset=0.0, connections=0.0, proxy=, difficulty=6.0E-8, testnet=false, keypoololdest=1.530817257E9, keypoolsize=2"[truncated 40 chars]; line: 1, column: 10]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1804) ~[jackson-core-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:669) ~[jackson-core-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:567) ~[jackson-core-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipColon2(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2198) ~[jackson-core-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._skipColon(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:2177) ~[jackson-core-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:685) ~[jackson-core-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3004) ~[jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar:2.9.6]
at com.example.demo.controller.MultichainController.getInfo(MultichainController.java:30) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:783) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
```

Any more advancements or updates I make, I will update this

**Note** I ultimately want to return a JSON response to an API call and I am not sure if I have to parse the JSON String to a POJO or else if I can just send the JSON String and it will get formatted in the backend

Comment: You have done it already. Spring will convert the info1 object to JSON for you and set the content type for you, too (assuming your spring configuration is correct). Ypur Spring (or Spring boot?) environment matters, but you're not saying anything about it. You also didn't say what happened when testing your code.

Comment: So yea its a very basic Spring web app that I got generated on start.spring.io. All I added was the controller class and the pojo. When I test, I am having issues converting the JSON String to the POJO. So I am asking how to do this or if there is an easier way of getting this done

Comment: So your question, which is how to send a JSON response, actually has nothing to do with your actual problem, which is "how to parse that non-JSON string to a POJO. How about asking us the actual question, and telling us what concrete problem you're facing (compilation error? which one? exception? which stack trace?)

Comment: Well ultimately I am not sure what to do. I can get a response but the value is just a string on the browser. Looking up information I tried parsing the String to a POJO but having parsing errors. So I'm not sure if I have to parse the JSON String to a POJO and return the POJO or else if there is a way just return the JSON String and it will be formatted on the backend

Comment: *but having parsing errors*: then at least tell us what the errors are.

Comment: Ill recreate locally and update the original question so

Comment: OK. Now the errors clearly tell what the problem is. You're trying to parse a string as if it was JSON, but clearly, it isn't: quotes are missing, equal sign is used instead of colon, missing values for some keys, etc. The conclusion should be straightforward: since it's not JSON, you shouldn't use a JSON parser to parse it. Write your own parser for this non-standard format.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the update. So to be clear, I have to write a custom parser to parse the String to the POJO and then return the POJO. This is the only way to show JSON in the browser?

Comment: It's not the only way, but it's the simplest one

Comment: I got it working, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

you should change your controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/publish/{signature}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) // import javax.ws.rs.core
public @ResponseBody Info getInfo(@PathVariable("signature") String signature) throws MultichainException, IOException {
//body
}
```